# Don't allow user to type in pipe character '|' in input form AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I know ng-pattern can be used to allow characters. I'm looking for a way to just limit one specific character.

My input box should work with any characters except the verticle bar '|' . I want to either throw an error just not allow it to be typed out. Is there an easy way to just not allow that specific character. Or should I just use ng-pattern to include EVERYTHING except the vertical bar? ( how would I do that?)

My html:

```
                     <td class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text"
                              name="Application"
                              ng-model="list.Application"
                              maxlength="64"
                              required />

                           <div ng-messages="addForm.Application.$error"
                                 ng-if="addForm.$submitted"

                        </div>
                    </td>
```

[image]

Comment: `ng-pattern` can be very simple :)

Comment: How do I use ng-pattern to just NOT ALLOW the verticle bar? Does that mean I have to use ng-pattern to allow EVERY possible character except that? Is there a better way?

Comment: What is wrong with negated character classes? Use one.

Comment: If you need more specific help please update the question with what regex pattern you tried.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know any regex. What regex should I use to allow everything except |

Comment: Check [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970). You will find it useful. See the bottom examples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew totally lost with the stuff haha. So you said use ^[^|]*$ to avoid the |. Does that mean All i do is just put that beside ng-pattern? Sorry totally new to programming

Comment: `ng-pattern="/^[^|]*$/"` if you want to allow an empty string, else `ng-pattern="/^[^|]+$/"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow it worked! now it pops an error when | is used! Thanks man! Wish I can come up with fast solutions like that =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an [`ng-pattern` attribute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) to the `input` and use a regex that will  restrict textual input.

This regex must match the text, thus, you need to check if the full input has no pipe symbols.

You need:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^|]*` - zero or more symbols other than `|` (replace `*` with `+` to disallow empty input)
- `$` - end of string.

Thus, use

```
ng-pattern="/^[^|]*$/"
```

The `/.../` are regex delimiters that will let angular know we are passing a regex object rather than a string.

Also, `ng-pattern="[^|]*"` should also work since string patterns are anchored by default in Angular.