# php regex for selecting anything but pure numbers

Tags: regex

I want to create a php regex to detect that a phrase is not pure numbers. 
My phrase is not in English so using patterns which contain [a-z] and [A-Z] is not useful.
point: I guess the pattern I need is anything except ^([0-9]{1,})$

Comment: You may use `/^(?!\d+$)/u` or `/^(?!\d+$).*$/su`

Comment: Just match the strings with this regex and put a `!` operator before `preg_match`! You don't have to do magic in the regex itself

Comment: Note I marked as a dupe because a lot of these scenarios are described in the http://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970 post, and your scenario is dealt with in the *a **string equal to some string** (say, not equal to `foo`):* section, where you just can use your own pattern `[0-9]{1,}` instead of `foo`.