# How to exclude a certain string from a pattern in regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern that matches a URL "slug" which I use to redirect all URI's with one segment that contain alphanumeric characters and hyphens(I.E. mysite.com/**about-us**) to my pages controller.  My problem is that I have a separate controller for my home page, so I want to exclude the string "home" from any matches. How can I do this with the pattern that I have below?

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

Comment: Try `^(?!.*home)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$`. It is not quite clear where `home` can appear in your string, and if you need to match it as a whole path part or word or just as a part of a string.

Comment: Like this:  mysite.com/home

Comment: @WiktorStribizew That worked perfectly!

Comment: And if you have mysite.com/somepath/here-is-your-home? The regex I shared will also "exclude" this path. Is it OK?

Comment: Might be a dupe of [Regex: match everything but](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970).