# regex match "everything but" with kebab-case for webpack

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, regex-negation

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but) example and tried using [this website](https://regex101.com/), but I am still stuck.

I need to match everything in the `node_modules` folder except `react-native-calendars` and it's subdirectories / children.

I think I need to use a Negative Lookahead, here is where I am at:

```
new RegExp (/node_modules\/(?!.*(react-native-calendars))/)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

Raw `^.*?/node_modules(?:/(?!react-native-calendars(?=/|$))[^/\r\n]*)*$`
Regex literal `/^.*?\/node_modules(?:\/(?!react-native-calendars(?=\/|$))[^\/\r\n]*)*$/`

It matches all items with the /`node_modules` folder and
sets a validation point at every `/` to check for the bad folder.

If you are using single item string's, you could remove the `(?m)`.
If you want it to be case insensitive, you could add `(?i)` if needed.
In JS, you'd add them to the literal syntax `/regex/mi`

I've already checked this, but if you had some sample input I could link
to an online tester (regex101.com).

Expanded

```
 ^                             # BOL
 .*?                           # Up until
 /node_modules                 # Required 'node_modules'
 (?:                           # Cluster
      /                             # / folder start
      (?!                           # Assert cannot be the bad folder
           react-native-calendars
           (?= / | $ )                   # Bad folder end
      )
      [^/\r\n]*                     # Ok, get up until start of next folder
 )*                            # Cluster end, do 0 to many times
 $                             # EOL
```

Comment: Is this in javacsript? I am getting `Invalid regular expression: /(?m)^.*?\/node_modules(?:\/(?!react-native-calendars(?=\/|$))[^\/\r\n]*)*$/` in my console (same for raw)

Comment: @pingo - Yeah, just take out the `(?m)` https://regex101.com/r/H2BKQt/2, add it to the delimiter form `//m` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `react-native-calendars` is a `node_modules` direct child folder:

```
/node_modules\/(?!react-native-calendars(?:\/|$)).*/
```

or

```
/node_modules\/(?!react-native-calendars(?![^\/])).*/
```

Comment: Thank you, how can i test this on regex101.com? I don't think a subject string would work.