# Regular expression containing all the text but a certain regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation, jflex

I come from here [Regex: match everything but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but) But they only say how to get a Regex containing all but some string.

What im trying to do is finding a regular expression that matches me all the text but this ^([\S+" "?]+" "@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})$ (or any other regex).

Comment: Could you provide an example of some text, and the text you are hoping to retrieve from it? Also, the ^ and $ match the start and end of the string respectively so the expression you specified will not match if there are leading or trailing characters.

Comment: I hope to match from this text:  "User Name @username Text Text Text Text random @thing"  This:  "Text Text Text Text random @thing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match words separated by spaces before a word starting with a `@` character;

`([^@\s]+ )+@[\w]{1,15}`

For example, this will return two matches for the String:

`User Name @username Text Text Text Text random @thing`

- `User Name @username`
- `Text Text Text Text random @thing`

You can then select the second match to get the text you need. Alternatively, if you know what `@thing` will be before compiling the regex (e.g. @response, @config, etc.) you can replace the `@[\w]{1,15}` section of the regex with the specific `@thing` to only retrieve the text you want.

Comment: The problem is that the text can have something that starts with "@" or not.

Comment: @Koalapa you need some way of determining where the text ends, whether that be a string starting with `@` or the end of the string. Is there some hard rule for where the text ends? Or how much text should be retrieved?

Comment: The text ends when it exceeds 140 chars afther that first @username.

Comment: But I guess the regex you gave me does the work. Thanks you very much

Comment: @Koalapa Depending on what language you're using you may be able to use this; `(?<=@username).{1,140}` which matches the first 140 characters after the string `@username` but requires the regex engine to support lookbehind (which javascript does not).