# Match anything.c but not anything.in.c

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches `a.c, hello.c, etc.c`, but not `a.in.c, hello.in.c, etc.in.c`.

Here's my regex: https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/21

It says that the negative lookahead won't match what I specified, that is, `.in.c`. I didn't know where to teach it to match `.c`. I tried both inside the parenthesis and outside.

I've read [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but) but it talks about matching everything except something, but I need to match a rule except other rule.

Comment: `^[^.]+(?!\.in)\.c` sort of works.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
.*(?<!(\.in))\.c
```

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

*Edited do to good information from zzxyz

Comment: this works well if your string is definitely a single filename and just a filename.  Probably good for the op.  Although it should probably be `\.in` to avoid `writein.c` from being filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit complicated given unknown input.  The following isn't perfect, but it avoids .cpp files, and deals with strings that don't contain filenames, or longer strings that do.

```
\b\S+(?<!\.in)\.c\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/286