# How to match something not defined

Tags: regex, jflex

if I have defined something like that

```
COMMAND         = "HI" | "HOW" | "ARE" | "YOU"
```

How can i say "if u match something that is not a COMMAND"?..

I tried with this one

```
[^COMMAND]
```

But didn't work..

Comment: But in that case u can match only a  word.. if you  write ^((?!BYE|HI).)*$ using OR operator doesn't work..

Comment: Im using Jflex.. it notice me like a syntax error.. can it be written differently?

Comment: No.. I think that in Flex is not possible .. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is not possible with (current) JFlex.

We would need an effective [tempered negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_gree): `((?!bad).)*`

There are two ways to do a negative lookahead in JFlex:

- negation in the lookahead: `x / !(y [^]*)` (match x if not followed by y in the lookahead).
- lookahead with negated elements: `x / [^y]|y[^z]` (match if x is followed by something that is !a or a!b.

Otherwise, you may get some ideas from this answer (specifically the lookaround alternatives): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/8291949

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just match anything else, then

```
COMMAND         = "HI" | "HOW" | "ARE" | "YOU" 
. {throw new RuntimeException("Illegal character: <" + yytext() + ">");}
```