# Regex for everything but a specific character not preceded by a string

Tags: java, regex

I am out of luck getting a regex build together which machtes everything but a specific character not preceded by a specific string.

For example this String:

```
Mr. Jones likes fish.
```

Should match like this:

```
Mr. Jones likes fish
```

And not for example:

```
Mr
```

I think this should be really easy but it just won't work. I already have it working for getting a correct match on the dot:

```
(?<!Mr)\.
```

The complementary match won't work though. I tried this:

```
(?<!Mr)[^.]*
```

Because i thought the cursor would be on the dot at that point and see that it was proceded by the "Mr" and it won't match. But it does.

And something like this:

```
(^((?<!Mr).))*
```

But the lookbehind in that regex is not recognized as one anymore and it just tries to match each character.

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but) answer but i couldn't find anythin helping me there.

Comment: Your question is good apart from the last paragraph (*im struggling*, *help me fast* etc).

Comment: Is the specific string "Mr"?

Comment: So you want a regexp to match anything except strings that has a `\.` after `Mr` somewhere? Is`Mr` always in the string only once?

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to match any character besides the period with the exception it is preceded by `Mr` so the regex could be [`"(?:[^.]+|(?<=Mr)\\.)+"`](https://regex101.com/r/N42EHf/1)

Comment: @Sylwester I want a regexp that matches everything but `\.` not preceded by a `Mr`. `Mr` can also be more often in the string.

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes! Thank you. That works perfectly. The `or` does the trick.

Comment: Great it helped, you're welcome

Comment: @bobblebubble If you post you comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looked to me, you want to match any character besides `.` with the exception that the period is preceded by `Mr` so you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)  (or an optional group) and a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?:[^.]+|(?<=Mr)\.)+
```

As a Java String: `"(?:[^.]+|(?<=Mr)\\.)+"`

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/N42EHf/1) (non Java)

- `(?:` opens a non capturing [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `[^.]+` matches one or more [characters that are not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `.`
- `(?<=Mr)\.` matches the period [only if preceded](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) by `Mr`