# How to say any character except dash ("-")

Tags: regex

How to do we compose a regex that says "the matches fails if there's a dash somewhere in the middle"

I have several lines that are composed as 3958.3r - 5v and some are without the dash for example: 3958.3v4r. I am able to get the ones with the dash, but not only the ones without the dash

Comment: So, you need both? Or want only without dash?

Comment: You want to match any string but [*a **string containing specific character***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970): `^[^-]*$` or `^[^-]+$` (if empty strings are not allowed).

Comment: @HardikShah I need to get first the ones with the dash only, and second the ones without the dash to store them somewhere for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a character class negation. `^` at the beginning of a character class simply negates the character class. If you then only have the character `-`, then you create a character class that matches anything but `-`.

```
^[^\-]+$
```

According to what you have said, you need to put the ^ (start of string) at the front of your pattern, and escape the `.` or else you will match not only the `.` after `395[0-9]`, but any character at all like `3950z`.

```
^395[0-9]\.[^-]+$
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. I have this regex constructed: `395[0-9].(.*?)^[^\-]+$`

Comment: see edits above

Comment: still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: My bad it worked finally I just misread the output

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the solution for anyone who views this later. Glad I could help.