# REGEX expression to ignore a part if string

Tags: regex, unix

I have strings like this in a file on unix machine

```
26 3 24 21 391
26 34 24
26 3 49 24 21 391
26 94 24
26 3 21 391
26 3 
27 3 24 21 391
2 94
```

Now I want to match more than one numbers at a time. These numbers are fixed ( constants) and doesn't need matching pattern to recognise them. So here if I want to match either 94 or 24 I will use below expression.

```
grep '\b\(94\|24\)\b' file_name.txt
```

But I actually need to find those string which has neither 94 nor 24. That means I want all the rows which not contains any of these numbers. I don't want to use options which come with grep ( like -v ).

EDIT:
Expected output -

```
26 3 21 391
26 3
```

Comment: Try `grep -Ev '\b[29]4\b' file`

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use options. Or write your own regex script.

Comment: @anubhava I have updated my question with expected output

Comment: So the answer for you in this case is "It is not possible". Please consider the listed alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a POSIX pattern to match a string not containing some multicharacter pattern.

You may use

```
grep -Ev '\b[29]4\b' file
```

The `-E` option enables the POSIX ERE compliance, the `\b[29]4\b` pattern matches `2` or `8` and then `4` as a whole word, and `v` inverts the results of a match.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/gXPb1P).

You may also use a PCRE regex without `v` option if your `grep` supports it:

```
grep -P '^(?!.*\b[29]4\b)' file
```

The `P` enables the PCRE regex engine, `^(?!.*\b[29]4\b)` matches the start of string with `^` and then fails all matches if, after 0+ chars, there is a `24` or `94` value as a whole word.

Comment: Thanks but as I have mentioned in my question, I can't use options which come with grep command.

Comment: @user2611539 Why don't you? BTW, what is your `grep` version?

Comment: I would be passing this regular expression to some other code which I don't have access to. I have to achieve it through Regex only.

Comment: @user2611539 It will be only possible if that code will parse the pattern with PCRE regex engine. Else, you can't do that with `grep` because you cannot write a POSIX pattern to match a string not containing some pattern.

Comment: If anyone thinks there is a way to write such a POSIX pattern, I'd be glad to add an example to my [Regex: match everything but](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970) answer.