# How to use regex to constrain a ReactJS Route

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, express, react-router

As said in [Regex: match everything but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but) in order to match everything but a string, you can use `^(?!foo$).*`

As seen here
https://regex101.com/r/9khSXB/2

But this doesn't work when using https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp specifically within ReactJS Routing (error -> invalid path)

```
<R.Route path="/^(?!\/whatsmyname$).*" render={() => <div>works!</div>} />
```

(also seen here http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/)

How can I write this regex in a node-friendly style?

UPDATE: this does work, you need the curly braces

```
<R.Route path={/^\/(?!whatsmyname$).*/} render={() => <div>works!</div>} />
```

Comment: Have a look here, that should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent - also note the answer below the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the curly braces

```
<R.Route path={/^\/(?!whatsmyname$).*/} render={() => <div>works!</div>} />
```