# Regex: How to match string which is not containing one certain character and it combinations side by side

Tags: regex

I am trying to match everything except * or ** or infinity number of *

I have already writed such regex:

```
^(?!\*).+$|^.*[^\*]$|(?<=\*).+
```

I need to add or statement which would remove match: '****'
Or write entire new one which:

Should not match when *

Should not match when **

Should not match when ***

ect.

---

Should match when A9()*

Should match when *A9()

Should match when *A*(*

Should match when A*()*

Should match when A9*)

Should match when A9()

ect.

Live example:
https://regex101.com/r/pw2z9E/1

Comment: This is worded in a confusing way, are you trying to match all strings that are not a single string of * characters?

Comment: I am trying to match everything except * or ** or infinity number of *

Comment: Should it match all strings, which do not contain multiple asterix marks in a row?

Comment: @nick if there is any character beside asterix than it should mark

Comment: `^(?!\*+$).*$`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew You are master of regex ;) I dont know how to mark your command as working one ..

Comment: I already answered this kind of question, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use length operator to determine minimum length of each symbol. For example:

`(\w{1,}\*{1,}|\w+)`

**UPD**

To include special characters use this modifications:

`([^*\s]{1,}\*{1,}|[^*\s]+)`

Comment: This one is working, thanks

Comment: @KamilSocha91 just updated the answer