# Regex to match letters and digits except 6 digit long number

Tags: regex

Can someone tell me how to allow in Regex all a-zA-Z0-9 except 6 digits long number?

So **true** for:

```
1234567

a123456 

123456P

3A237bdb8
```

but **false** for

```
123456
```

**I want to**

**allow** only letters and digits

**deny** 6 digit long number (like 123456) and other not letter characters like -_+,.!@#$ etc.

Comment: See [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970) (scroll to *a string equal to some string*)

Comment: And note that the string can also be any regex, such as `\d{6}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: My intent is to allow all letters and digits except exactly 6 digit long number. I do not want to allow space, dots, commas,  and other characters that can be a string.

Comment: `$s =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ and $s !~ /^\d{6}$/`?

Comment: @Biffen I know regex and I use it for a long time. I just don't know how to handle this particular case which is difficult to me to fulfil. I know that there are many materials about Regex but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Biffen thank you but this ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ allow all letter and digits but doesn't exclude 6 digit long number. This ^\d{6}$ works almost but allows characters like -_ etc. But I want to allow only a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: @Tom They’re two different pattern for testing two different things. One should match and the other shouldn’t. Much easier to read than one complex pattern.

Comment: How about: `^(?!\d{6}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3UBqj3/1)

Comment: @Toto this is it!!! Thank you. Can you write this as an answer? So I had thought it in a wring way. I wanted to allow something and exclude something else while this was just a matter of excluding something from the beginning. This is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regex engine supports lookahead, you can use:

```
^(?!\d{6}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3UBqj3/1)