# Getting an error on negating a pattern in regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement a regex for matching all characters except the first character and any character followed by `_` in a single word as:

```
"HELLO_WORLD".replace(^([A-Z]|/_[A-Z]),f => f.toLowerCase()) // Hello_World
```

But this is giving me error as :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^
```

Can anybody point whats wrong ?
I am following this question basically [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern)

EDIT:

This is happening due to missing string literal but I have a followup question now that my regex is not working as I want.

```
"HELLO_WORLD".replace(/^([A-Z]|_[A-Z])/,f => f.toLowerCase()) // hELLO_WORLD
```

This is giving `hELLO_WORLD` when I want `Hello_World`

Comment: [Regex literals start and end with a slash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). That isn't syntactically valid Javascript. The syntax highlighting on your question should have tipped you off.

Comment: okay thanks, I missed it. But my regex looks crooked too. Its not doing what I want.
whats wrong there

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59081300/edit) if your code has changed

Comment: That's a separate question.

Comment: I was in process of editing. Thanks all.

Comment: You have an unescaped `/` and missing `)` in your regex

Comment: @Phil that was a typo , can you check now ?

Answer (score 1):

The caret `^` should be inside of the alternation if you want to match either A-Z at the start of the string OR _A-Z in the string.

You are only replacing a single character to lowercase as you are not using the `g` global flag.

You could use 2 capturing groups using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of 1 where the second capturing group matches 1+ times A-Za-z and that match will be replaced to lowercase.

```
(^[A-Z]|_[A-Z])([A-Za-z]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aq8W2h/1)

```js
let result = "HELLO_WOrLD".replace(/(^[A-Z]|_[A-Z])([A-Za-z]+)/g, (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.toLowerCase());
console.log(result);
```