# Exclude a specific string from a RegEx expression in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-negation

I have the following basic RegEx expression in Google Analytics that consists of a list of city names.

`(toronto|vancouver|calgary|halifax|winnipeg|ottawa|edmonton|regina|mississauga)`

I would like to add another expression to the query such that a result is **not** returned if the matching text also has the word "job" in it.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern

Comment: Easy with .Net, use a lookbehind and a lookahead

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: not so easy, because the lookbehind is not allowed to contain regular expressions inside of it.

Comment: @Pierre Lookbehinds are regexes  and in .net they can contain any length matching patterns.

Comment: @BlackPearl I believe that this is the same suggestion made by Pierre Francois but it doesn't seem to work in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited answer] This works:

```
^((?!job).)*(toronto|vancouver|calgary|halifax|winnipeg|ottawa|edmonton|regina|mississauga)(?!.*job)
```

It matches the city names only if "job" is not present before or after the city name.

See https://regex101.com/r/tXfBGf/3

Comment: When I enter this into Google Analytics, I receive the following error: "Invalid regular expression. Your data request includes an invalid regular expression.". Thoughts?

Comment: GA regex engine is RE2 and it doesn't support lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there an alternate solution that might work in GA?

Comment: @zgall1 Probably you may do that using exclude filters.

Answer (score -1):

Provided your flavor of regex includes capture groups, this is easily solved using [The Best Regex Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html), prior exclusion. Essentially:

`"string".match(/(?:a|b|c)job|(a|b|c)/).match_group(1)`, where:
`?:`: Do not save the prior exclusion in a capture group;
`(a|b|c)job` are the strings to avoid capturing;
`|(a|b|c)` are the strings to capture.

This works because if the text matches the undesirable text, `ajob`, then the capture group is never populated. It will only be populated if the desired text `a` is matched without `ajob`

Comment: I am not able to follow how this concept can be applied to my specific case.

Comment: If you can write a regex that matches the text you don't want (e.g text matching /job/) then you can use this technique to convert that to matching on text you DO want while excluding those forbidden contexts.

Comment: Perhaps if you can clarify what you mean by "has the word 'job' in it" I can write a more specific regex to your case; for example, are you encountering text like `winnijobpeg`? I doubt it, so I used the simpler example of city followed by job a la `winnipegjob`

Comment: The word job is always separated from other characters by either a slash (/job/winnipeg) or a dash (job-winnipeg).

Comment: then use`/job[-\/](?:winnipeg|toronto|...)|(winnipeg|toronto|...)/`, match group 1. Sample here: https://regex101.com/r/jBfTeE/1 Pay close attention to the match group panel on the right side.