# How to remove any given string pairs from text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, .net-4.8

Unfortunately my regex skills are very bad

I would like to code a function that can remove any given pair of strings and whatever between them

For example

```
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as op<!--posed to using--> 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages <!--and web page<!-- asdasasdas--> editors now use--> Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
```

From this above example text, i want to remove these string pairs and whatever inside them `<!--` `-->`

After removal the example text become as below

```
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as op 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages  Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
```

Are there any readily function for this task? I don't want a specific regex for this

It should a function which takes 3 parameters

parameter 1 : the text

parameter 2 : the beginning part of string pair e.g.  `<!--`

parameter 3 : the end part of string pair e.g. `-->`

Using latest .net framework 4.8+

edit

the linked answer for example fails at this

```
ing packages <!--and web page<!-- asdasasdas--> editors now use--> Lorem Ipsum
```

Moreover, it has to work with multi-line as well

such as

```
    ok like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages
 <!--
and web page<!-- asdasasdas--> editors no
    w use--> Lorem Ipsum as their de
```

will become

```
    ok like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages


     Lorem Ipsum as their de
```

here example in code

[image]

here samples. sample 4 currently not working

https://dotnetfiddle.net/mA3waq

Comment: The linked answer does not handle inner string pairs. I have updated my question

Comment: The following regex should work. Be sure there's no whitespace i missed when trimming it for the comment format, but this will match nested `<!--...-->`; here's the regex: `<!--(?>(?!<!--|-->).|<!--(?<D>)|-->(?<-D>))*(?(D)(?!))-->`

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman no i am not looking for specific solution. it has to be generic for every string pairs

Comment: What do you mean? How is a regex supposed to know what the string pair is if you don't specify it? What are some examples of other string pairs you want to match? This matches in your test case, so you really need to provide more information as to why if this solution doesn't work.

Comment: If you use String.Format on this, with {0} being the opening delimiter and {1} being the closing delimiter, it will do what you're asking. `{0}(?>(?!{0}|{1}).|{0}(?<D>)|{1}(?<-D>))*(?(D)(?!)){1}` - Just be certain to escape whatever you format in using `Regex.Escape` if it has any special characters, or this will blow up in your face

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman yes certainly the text can have special characters. moreover, it should work with multi-line as well

Comment: If you need it to match across multiple lines, then you need to use the single line regex option so that `.` matches `\n`, or replace the `.` with `[\w\W]` - as for the special characters, `Regex.Escape` on your delimiters before formatting them into the regex will solve that problem.

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman thanks for answer but i really am bad with regex. i have put an image to the question can you check that and post a full answer if possible?

Comment: No I cannot, your question is closed as a duplicate. `string FilterString(string source, string beginpattern, string endpattern) {return Regex.Replace(source,String.Format("{0}(?>(?!{0}|{1}).|{0}(?<D>)|{1}(?<-D>))*(?(D)(?!)){1}",Regex.Escape(beginpattern),Regex.Escape(endpattern)),String.Empty,RegexOptions.SingleLine)}`

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman yes it is working even with multi line. why dont you post as answer so i can mark as answer. by the way in which cases it would not work?

Comment: I cannot post a new answer because your question is closed by moderators as a duplicate; consider adopting my answer into the question - or, if it still allows you to self-answer (I can't remember if they still allow that for closed questions), you are free to self-answer with my function.

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman it seems like i can not also answer. i will try to get this question re-opened. moreover some special characters could break it you said. which are those? also i have tested 3 nested string and still worked. it should work with as many as nested string pairs right?

Comment: Yes, it uses .NET balancing groups to match as many nested pairs as there are in the string. Balancing groups are really interesting, I highly recommend giving them a look some time!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex build in runtime with delimiter strings. For example,

```
string FilterString(string source, string beginPattern, string endPattern)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex($"\\{beginPattern}.*\\{endPattern}",RegexOptions.Singleline);
    return regex.Replace(source, string.Empty);
}
```

Sample Input

```
packages <!--and web page<!-- asdasasdas--> editors now use--> Lorem
```

Output

```
packages  Lorem
```

[Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sf6UiD)

Comment: just tested and it fails with this  "packages <!--and web page<!-- asdasasdas--> editors now use--> Lorem"

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I have updated the result, could you please verify

Comment: now works but gets broken when text is multi-line. can you modify further?

Comment: anyway to make it multi line supporting?. thank you very much for help. i have updated question and added image

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Please check the updated answer. I have updated the sample link as well

Comment: i have added sample 4 to your link and when you check you will see that it removes part that it is not supposed to remove here > https://dotnetfiddle.net/mA3waq