# Regular expression find and replace if not text in sublime text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, regexp-replace

I'm using regular expression to replace `<a href="**Replace**">` links in my html like this:

FIND: `<a(.+)href="([^"]+)"([^>]+)?>`
REPLACE (But dont delete "[Nottobedeleted]"): `<a\1href="[INSERT NEW URL HERE]"\3>`

Is there any way you could make it so if some text appears like "Nottobedeleted" that it just jumps over that?

Comment: If you mean `href="([^"]+)"` can have `Nottobedeleted` then `href="(?!Nottobedelted")([^"]+)"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern will help you find out what you need.