# Regex: regex match everything but specific pattern

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-negation

I need a regex that finds values other than `!#!` in a string.

If, for example, the string were:

```
Text1!#!Text2!#!Text#3!#!
```

it should return `Text1`, `Text2`, `Text#3`

`[^!#!]` would match the `#` in `Text#3` as well, which I don't want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern)

Comment: @Prakash S - Which regex flavor is used?

Comment: What's to become of `**`? If you split the string on `!#!`, for example, you get an array containing `Text1**`, `Text2`, `Text#3` and `**`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I suspect that the `**` were intended to be _markup_ for bold text, i.e. they are not part of the actual data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's correct, Have edited the data correctly now

Comment: @PoulBak I tried that , but that does seem to be working for me

Comment: @PrakashS Are you using a programming language?

Comment: @Armali am trying to use it with oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: @TimBiegeleiseno am using it with oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: What is your language from which you run your regex? Why use a regex at all and not simply split the string on your fixed pattern `!#!`, then loop over each element in the resulting array?

Comment: This type of problem is not well suited to Oracle (nor to most SQL databases).  You should probably handle this requirement outside of Oracle.

Comment: Prakash, note that `[^!#!]` is the same as `[^!#]` and matches any single character other than `!` and `#`.

Comment: Previous developer has written it in regex way in one of the stored procedure and I'm trying to fix a bug here and don't have much experience in Oracle, so thought just changing the regex would solve the issue

Comment: @CarySwoveland Got it , is there any way to look for this specific pattern '!#!' in regex.  So i have a many values which stored as a string and separated by '!#!' by this pattern, If i have '#' in one of the values then i won't get the correct data with [^!#!]

Comment: Would this column always have exactly three components to it?  Or, could there sometimes be greater or fewer than 3?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It could be more than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) in conjunction with `CONNECT_BY` to split the string into words separated by `!#!`. We use the regex:

```
(.*?)(!#!|$)
```

which matches some number of characters lazily until it encounters either `!#!` or the end of string (`$`).

For example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Text1!#!Text2!#!Text#3!#!',
                      '(.*?)(!#!|$)',
                      1,
                      LEVEL,
                      '',
                      1)
              AS VAL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Text1!#!Text2!#!Text#3!#!',
                          '(.*?)(!#!|$)',
                          1,
                          LEVEL,
                          '',
                          1)
IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
VAL
Text1
Text2
Text#3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0f0f820a93b7059abb6dda48d6ae4553)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem using positive lookbehind and lookahead.

Simply:

- match anyhting `(.+?)`
- being at the beginning of the text or having the pattern in front `(?<=^|!#!)`
- and being at the end of the text or having the pattern behind `(?=!#!|$)`

See your example here: https://rubular.com/r/f6BDr9CxeaQTIz using `(?<=^|!#!)(.+?)(?=!#!|$)`

Comment: Note that Oracle's regex engine does _not_ support lookarounds.  While this might be a general solution, it will not work for Oracle.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so we can't fix this issue with regex in Oracle then?

Comment: If your Oracle tables contain this type of data, then your data is pretty far from being normalized.  You should fix your data model.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the limitations of Oracles regex engine. But maybe you can just match the expression with a simple pattern (e.g. `(.+?!#!)`) and then remove the pattern in a second step?