# matching beginning of string and excluding end of string in regex

Tags: regex, go

I have some strings like the following:

```
abc4back
abc4backpre
abc4front
abc4frontpre
abc3side
abc3sidepre
xyz4over
xyz4overpre
```

and I want to get those only with the "abc4" but without the "pre". So far, my regex is: 
`abc4.*(?!pre)`.

But, when I ran this, I got the error: 
`` error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!` `` .

I now know that this is because lookaheads are not supported in go.

But, I cannot figure out what expression I should use instead of `?!`. Does anyone know what will work?

Comment: is `pre` always at the end of the string?

Comment: Even if the regex engine supported lookarounds, your regex is wrong, you would need `abc4(?!.*pre)` or even `^abc4(?!.*pre$)`. You can re-write the lookahead using an alternation of negated character classes as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by multi negated character as

`^abc4(?:.*(?:[^p].{2}|p[^r].{1}|pr[^e])|.{0,2})$`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5AETu/1/)