# Adding words to a character class in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am currently using the following character class:
`[^\)\(]` in my regex

I want to add the word 'hello' to this class so it is also not matched in my string.
I have tried

`[^\)\((hello)]`

but it does not work.

What can I do?

Comment: Duplicate of [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word), [match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687620/8967612).

Comment: You could very well use `[^t()]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One typical way you would enforce that `hello` does not appear would be to use a negative lookahead, e.g.

```
^(?!.*hello)[^t()]+$
```

If you only wanted to exclude `hello` when it appears as a bona fide word, then surround it with word boundaries in the lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\bhello\b)[^t()]+$
```