# Create regex pattern to exclude a string

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex pattern to allow all the string with:
gallery-a

or strings which start with gallery-a than a white space and after each string is accepted except clip-a.

Examples:

```
gallery-a ACCEPTED
gallery-a kfjrgrgl elrgkelk ACCEPTED
gallery-a clip-a NOT ACCEPTED
```

I tried with `^gallery-a((?!clip-a).)*$` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Duplicate of [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern), [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/8967612).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^gallery-a(?!.*clip-a).*
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/5pGYbM/2/).