# Display all these strings NOT matching the regex

Tags: regex, search, replace, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have following strings

```
hdt-h
e2emin-n1
deep-p1
e2emax-s1
103-abc-p1
kru-02c-p1
xyz-ghg-r1
aaa-b20-p3

aaa-r24-p3
dfe-b2c-p2
hjq-b2b-p6
oru-xmn-p8
```

And I have following regex `^[a-z]{3}-[a-z][a-z1-9]{2}-p[1-9]$` which correctly matches last four strings in the example above.

However, now I want to display all these strings which are **not** matching the above regex. Basically I want to display the first 8 strings.

These 'incorrect' strings can take any form, there can be dashes, periods or commas inside it, and so on. That's why I need to find all these not fitting the correct form.

I tried ?! but didn't work form me.

Comment: If supported, you can use a negative lookahead `^(?![a-z]{3}-[a-z][a-z1-9]{2}-p[1-9]$)[a-zA-Z0-9.,-]+$` https://regex101.com/r/0DdNWj/1

Comment: Would you want to match a string that was just the exclamation mark, `!` (that is **not** one of the last 4 strings either)?

Comment: Matching any string not "equal" to some pattern: `^(?!pattern$).*`. [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970)

Comment: Both suggestions worked for me. Thanks!