# Firebase redirect using Regex

Tags: regex, firebase, redirect, firebase-hosting

My goal is to redirect any URL that does not start with a specific symbol ("#") to a different website.
I am using Firebase Hosting and already tried the Regex function in redirect to achieve this. I followed this firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config?hl=de) on redirects but because I new to regular expressions I assume that my mistake might be my regex code.

My Goal:

- mydomain.com/anyNotStartingWith# => otherdomain.com/anyNotStartingWith#
- mydomain.com/#any => mydomain.com/#any

My Code:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    ...
    "redirects": [
      {
        "regex": "/^[^#]:params*",
        "destination": "otherdomain.com/:params",
        "type": 301
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `"regex": "/(?P<params>[^/#][^/]*)"`, or `"regex": "/(?P<params>[^/#].*)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your help, both work!
is there a way to add to this expression something to check if the URL ends with .js and also don't allow this.
so that mydomain.com/any.js is not redirected either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
"regex": "/(?P<params>[^/#].*)"
```

The point is that you need a capturing group that will match and capture the part you want to use in the `destination`. So, in this case

- `/` - matches `/`
- `(?P<params>[^/#].*)` - Named capturing group `params` (you can refer to the group from the `destination` using `:params`):

  - `[^/#]` - any char other than `/` and `#`
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

To avoid matching files with `.js`, you can use

```
/(?P<params>[^/#].*(?:[^.].{2}$|.[^j].$|.{2}[^s]$))$
```

See [this RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nr9wmL/1)

See more about how to negate patterns at [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern/37988661#37988661).