# REGEX match all python (.py) files in any directory, except where the filename is X

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I think this should have been answered many times but I just can't find an answer specific enough.

I'm using a python linting tool that only has a 'match' regular expression (no excludes).
So the expression to match any python file in the working directory is currently

```
match=^.*\.py$
```

However there's a limitation in the linter and it fails when files have bad permissions.
I'm not interested in reasons I just want the linter to ignore those files via the match regex.

So how can I create a regex expression for the match such that for the following :

```
foo.py
/blah/bar.py
/som/dir/gnar.py
/an/dir/IGNOREME.py
/an/other/dir/IGNOREME.py
/foo.notgoodext
```

matches everything with a .py extension
EXCEPT when the filename is IGNOREME (in any directory)

So it will match the first, second and third file, but not the last three

I know this has something to do with 'negative lookahead' but I just can't get it to work!

Comment: It means *match anything but the string that ends with*: `^(?!.*/IGNOREME.py$).*\.py$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, I got it to work from there

Comment: If you find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970) lacks something, please let me know, I will update.