# How to apply re.sub() with exceptions

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to program a vocabulary game.

I am using a regular expression to hide my word, which I have to guess. I'm not comfortable with the syntax used with regular expressions - outwith the simple examples, I get very confused.

Take for example the verb

```
'to crank (sth) up'
```

I want to transform that into:

```
to   _ _ _ _ _   (sth)  _ _
```

The programme will feed from a vocabulary CSV file. My convention is to add `(sth)` or `(smb)` for transitive verbs. I don't want to hide those bits between brackets. Likewise, I don't want to hide the `to` that denotes the infinitive tense.

The transformations I'm applying so far are:

```
chosen_word = "to crank (sth) up"

# To make the space between words double for better legibility
hidden_word = re.sub("\s", "  ", chosen_word)

# To hide the letters of the word 
hidden_word = re.sub("[a-z]", "_ ", hidden_word)
```

But that results in:

```
_ _    _ _ _ _ _   ( _ _ _ )  _ _
```

How can I code a `re.sub()` method that transforms all alphabetical characters to `_`  **except** the patterns `to` **and** `sth` and `smb`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern)

Comment: Although I flagged as a duplicate, I want to say that regex is probably not the right way to solve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the exclusions and then use a dynamic replacement pattern:

```py
hidden_word = re.sub(r"(\bto\b|\(s(?:th|b)\))|[a-z]", lambda x: x.group(1) or "_ ", hidden_word)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Y6nkgs). *Regex details*:

- `(\bto\b|\(s(?:th|b)\))` - Group 1: either a whole word `to` or `(sth)` or `(sb)`
- `|` - or
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `lambda x: x.group(1) or "_ "` - the match is either replaced with Group 1 value (if it was matched) or with an underscore plus space otherwise.

Comment: Many thanks Wiktor, it works wonderfully! 

To ensure I understand this bit:

`lambda x: x.group(1) or "_ "`

What is the relationship between the integer '1' and the previous RegEx? You talk about Group 1 - is that the RegEx _captured_ with the outermost, non-escaped parentheses, which is to the left of the '|' symbol?

Comment: @XavierVillàAguilar See the `(\bto\b|\(s(?:th|b)\))` explanation, it is *Group 1*. `x.group(1)`  refers to the part of a match captured with that group. Capturing groups are set with a pair of unescaped parentheses.