# regex to filter out string

Tags: java, regex

I'm filtering out string using below regex

```
^(?!.*(P1 | P2)).*groupName.*$
```

Here group name is specific string which I replace at run time. This regex is already running fine.

I've two input strings which needs to pass through from this regex. Can't change `^(?!.*(P1 | P2))` part of regex, so would like to change regex after this part only. Its a very generic regex which is being used at so many places, so I have only place to have changes is `groupName` part of regex. Is there any way where only `2` string could pass through this regex ?

```
1) ADMIN-P3-UI-READ-ONLY
2) ADMIN-P3-READ-ONLY
```

In regex `groupName` is a just a variable which will be replaced at run time with required string. In this case I want `2` string to be passed, so `groupName` part can be replaced with `READ-ONLY` but it will pass `1` string too.

Can anyone suggest on this how to make this work ?

Comment: Try compiling it with `Pattern.COMMENTS` option, or prepend the pattern string with `(?x)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this is not working. Wiktor, is there any way I could check whole string more than one with one regex pattern. Like putting AND condition and if string matches all AND condtion then return true.

Comment: Yes, `^(?=condition1)condition2`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, tried this...not working (?=^(?!.*(?:P1 | P2)).*Admin.*$)(?=^(?!.*(?:UI)).*$)   is it correct ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you also want to fail the strings containing `UI`? Like `^(?!.*UI)(?!.*(P1|P2)).*READ-ONLY.*$`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQyd1s/1).

Comment: Do you also want to fail the strings containing UI? Yes..!  And why I cannot add this ^(?!.*UI) in end ?

Comment: Because `^` matches the start of string. You can also use it like this: `^(?!.*UI)^(?!.*(P1|P2)).*READ-ONLY.*$` (that is, use it at the start).

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: @Wiktor Yes working ..! but its not that much generic I was looking for..! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative lookBehind:

```
(?<!UI-)READ-ONLY
```

so there must be no UI- before READ-ONLY

Answer (score 0):

You can add another lookahead at the very start of your pattern to further restrict what it matches because your pattern is of the ["match-everything-but"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern) type.

So, it may look like

```java
String extraCondition = "^(?!.*UI)";
String regex = "^(?!.*(P1|P2)).*READ-ONLY.*$";
String finalRegex = extraCondition + regex;
```

The pattern will look like

```java
^(?!.*UI)^(?!.*(P1|P2)).*READ-ONLY.*$
```

matching

- `^(?!.*UI)`  - no `UI` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible from the start of string
- `^(?!.*(P1|P2))` - no `P1` nor `P2` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible from the start of string
- `.*READ-ONLY` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `READ-ONLY`
- `.*$` - the rest of the string. **Note** you may safely remove `$` here unless you want to make sure there are no extra lines in the input string.