# How can i add a character at the beginning of a field content?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

i'm trying to add a single character at the beginning of field content in logstash. I found on web only how to add it at the end using gsub plugin, like this:

```
dissect {
        mapping => {"message" => "%{message}<%{payload}"}
      }
      mutate {
        gsub => ["payload", "$", "<"]
      }
```

but if I would to add "<" at the beginning, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter in your question uses a regex to find where to place the `<`. With `$`, it's matching the end of the string

```
mutate {
   gsub => ["payload", "$", "<"]
}
```

The regex to find the start of the string is `^`. So you'll have to modify your filter like this:

```
mutate {
   gsub => ["payload", "^", "<"]
}
```

If you want to only add the `<` when it's not present:

```
mutate {
   gsub => ["payload", "^", "^(?!<)"]
}
```

Here the `(?!<)` part of the regex checks if the `<` is not present ([negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1687663/6113627)); if there's already one, the regex won't match and no `<` get added.

Comment: and if i wanted to put "<" only if it doesn't exist at beginning is possible?

Comment: Thank you, you're an angel. Is there a website where to find this regex?

Comment: I added a link to the question where I found the regex syntax (I knew it existed, but not the exact syntax). When working with regex, I usually use regex101.com to test them (for example [here](https://regex101.com/r/U8Sc0x/1) what I used in your case).