# Regex | How to exclude specific patterns of characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

In question, I need a Regex to accept everything except for **specific** patterns of strings. I've tried using negative lookahead examples from this Stackoverflow Question Forum:

[Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern)

But it looks that the patterns of words are different than a pattern of characters.

**The patterns I need to exclude are the ones listed below:**

[image: Character patterns to exclude]

Comment: So, *how* did you use them? *Where*?

Comment: I tried using them like this: `^(?!.*:[^\\])$` but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why did you glue the `$` anchor? There is no example like this at the page you linked to. There is a clear example, like `^(?!.*patternToExclude)`. If you have more patterns, simply use `^(?!.*patternToExclude)(?!.*patternToExclude2)(?!.*patternToExclude3)`. Besides, if you use `"^(?!.*:[^\\])"` in Java or `"~^(?!.*:[^\\])~"` in PHP, you will get an exception.

Comment: Those are string patterns, the `/` character for example, can't be excluded like that, because it's marked as a pattern error, the `$` is only to declare the end of the regex.

Comment: `$` does not declare regex end. You never need any markers for that. `$` requires the end of string position.

Comment: Ok I understand that, but this `^(?!.*://)` doesn't work either, that's what I'm trying to exclude..

Comment: No, [it works well](https://regex101.com/r/rlZVu9/1). You are just using it in a wrong way. But we do not know how.

Comment: So, which is the right way? I wouldn't be here asking for help if I knew the answer...

Comment: We can't help you because you are not revealing ***how and where*** you are using the regexps. Add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: Maybe you're using javascript, in which case you need to escape the `//` with `\/\/`? But as Wiktor says, you haven't given us any context for how you're using them so it makes it difficult for us to imagine what is going wrong; if you provide a snippet of code with the exact code which is failing then we might be better placed to help you :)

Comment: I need to use the regex to detect when those patterns are used on an input box, so I can show an error message. There's no code failing yet, because I'm trying to build the regex at regex101.com but it says pattern error.

Comment: regex101 usually gives you very detailed information about what the error is; can you copy the whole output for us?

Comment: Sure:
`All the errors detected are listed below, from left to right, as they appear in the pattern.
/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)
/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of excluding the patterns:

```
^(?!.*:\/\/)(?!.*\.\.\/)(?!.*:\\)$
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).