# Python regex and use of character class to filter out data

Tags: python, regex, character-class

I have list of hostnames. They are represented by region code.

1. AP- : APAC
2. EM- : EMEA
3. AM- : Americas

Actual list has around 1000 hostnames and idea is to filter out hostname with no region code in them. I am able to filter it out by string manipulation etc however I am wondering how could I write an efficient regex to filter the hostname with no region codes in it ( like last 4 item in the list )  ?

```
 import re

host_name = ["XXX_Guangzhou_AP-CN-BEI-7517","XXX_Jakarta_AP-ID-JAK-0001","XXX_TaiPei_AP-TW-TPE-0002","XXX_Dubai_EM-AE-DUB-1012",
"XXX_Viladecans_EM-ES-VIL-1002","XXX_Ringsted_EM-DK-RIN-0001","XXX_Bogota_AM-CO-BOG-1033","XXX_Hamburg_EM-DE-HAM-1004",
"XXX_Bangkok_TH127","XXX_Bangkok_TH124","XXX_Eagan_6231","XXX_Martinez_AR218"]

hostRegex = re.compile(r"[^(AP\-|EM\-|AM\-)]")
mo = list(filter(hostRegex.findall,host_name))
print(mo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
hostRegex = re.compile(r"_(A[PM]|EM)-")
mo = list(filter(lambda x: not hostRegex.search(x),host_name))
```

The `_(A[PM]|EM)-` [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/tQiBZv/1) `_`, then `AP`, `AM` or `EM`, and then a `-` char.

The `filter(lambda x: not hostRegex.search(x),host_name)` part returns all items in the `host_name` list that have no match.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QEAFqr):

```py
import re

host_name = [
    "XXX_Guangzhou_AP-CN-BEI-7517","XXX_Jakarta_AP-ID-JAK-0001","XXX_TaiPei_AP-TW-TPE-0002",
    "XXX_Dubai_EM-AE-DUB-1012","XXX_Viladecans_EM-ES-VIL-1002","XXX_Ringsted_EM-DK-RIN-0001",
    "XXX_Bogota_AM-CO-BOG-1033","XXX_Hamburg_EM-DE-HAM-1004", "XXX_Bangkok_TH127","XXX_Bangkok_TH124",
    "XXX_Eagan_6231","XXX_Martinez_AR218"]

hostRegex = re.compile(r"_(A[PM]|EM)-")
mo = list(filter(lambda x: not hostRegex.search(x),host_name))
print(mo)
```

Output:

```
['XXX_Bangkok_TH127', 'XXX_Bangkok_TH124', 'XXX_Eagan_6231', 'XXX_Martinez_AR218']
```

Comment: Thanks you Wiktor.  Could you please help me with a negative character regex ?

Comment: @RohitVerma All you need is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern), `r"^(?!.*_(A[PM]|EM)-)"`