# regcomp() error in (apparently) valid regular expression

Tags: c, regex

I have the following regex:

```
^(?!avoid).*
```

I have checket that it works, using https://regex101.com/:

[image]

However, if I try to compile it using [regcomp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) in a C program like this:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(void)
{
   regex_t preg;
   char    *pattern = "^(?!avoid).*";
   int     rc;
   char    buffer[100];
 
   if (0 != (rc = regcomp(&preg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED))) {
      regerror(rc, &preg, buffer, 100);
      printf("regcomp() failed with '%s'\n", buffer);
      exit(-1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
regcomp() failed with 'Invalid preceding regular expression'
```

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: POSIX regex does not support lookarounds. See the  top of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970) for the POSIX workaround for strings that do not start with some specific string.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Is regex.h the only regular expression library in C/C++? Maybe there are alternative libraries supporting lookarounds?

Comment: Sure, for C++, the most common workaround is using Boost `boost::regex`.